# JavaScript -- insert "\r\n" at every line break in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, csv

I'm trying to use this [CSV parsing library](https://github.com/knrz/CSV.js) to parse my CSV, but it seems that this library needs "\r\n\" to be at the end of every row.

Right now, my CSV looks like this:

```
Bob, Smith, Cats,
Annie, Johnson, Dogs
```

How do I add the string "\r\n\" right after "Cats" and "Dogs"? Or is this unnecessary? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this is a valid csv?

Comment: Once I read it in using the native FileReader API, the output is that string.

Comment: If that is your csv, it already has an `\r\n`, or, at lest an `\n`.  That is what puts the next portion of the string on the next line.  And, i doubt it is supposed to have quotation marks.

Comment: If you do a `console.log(yourCsvData);` ..what does it print?

Comment: The `\r\n` aren't expected to appear within `.csv` files. They are only used in the demos because they're defined with string literals in code rather than with separate files. [MDN: Using special characters in strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings). The sequence in a string represents the [default Windows newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF#Representations), CRLF.

Comment: If you created the file from within Windows, chances are that your file already contains "\r\n" at the end of line 1. If that's the case, your parser [should] see 2 lines. I noticed that you removed your quotes, but when you added the comma to the end of the first line, you told the parser that there is a blank field in row one, for a total of 4 fields, whereas line 2 only has 3 fields. I must add that it is simpler to write your own CSV parser than to learn somebody else's, especially if your data is already normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what works for your environment!

You could change the default `'\r\n'` to `'\n'` like below:

```
var csv = new CSV(data, { line: '\n' });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes sense! In the example above, what line break should I feed in? Will the parser interpret "\n" as a line break or a string?

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I have not worked with the parser myself, but from the looks of documentation on github, it should interpret as line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var text = "Box, Smith, Cats\nAnnie, Johnson, Dogs";
text = text.split( "\n" ).join( "\r\n" );
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53uT3/)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the documentation indeed says you can simply specify the line characters yourself with the `line` option as already pointed out in the other answer.

Just providing some additional info on this:

**\r** stands for **carriage return**
**\n** stands for **line feed (newline)**
Depending on which program you used to generate or manually write the CSV file, when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will produce either `\n` or `\r\n`

You can 'pre-cure' this with a text editor like Notepad++, Sublime Text, Brackets, etc. which have a regex replace feature. (<kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> to bring it up in most cases). Most notably, Notepad++ allows you to **see all characters** in the View menu (\r will show up as a block with CR & \n will show up as a block with LN).

Simply check the Regex checkbox or icon and replace all `\n` with `\r\n` or vice versa.